# ASP.NET: EventHandler issue on Button object in Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have 64 buttons on my page that represent a team (it's a sort of NCAA bracket type thing). The buttons on page load are stored into a Dictionary as a key. Team is an object that stores information about the team. On the initial page load, the event handlers are built, but when the page reloads after a submit by clicking one of the buttons, the handler disappears. When I tried to have it add them on every page load, I checked the handlers after they are added, and they're still not there anymore.

Is this an issue accessing the original object via the Dictionary?

I'm using it like this:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Button, Team> tb in TeamButtons){
    tb.Key.Click += new EventHandler(Tournament_Click);
}
```

Any ideas?

Page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<Team> teamlist;
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            using (Db db = new Db(ServerConnection.DEV))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dr = db.GetData("SELECT A.TeamId, A.Description 'TeamName', A.Seed, A.RegionId, B.Quadrant, B.Description 'RegionName' " +
                                                    "FROM Team A JOIN Region B on B.RegionId = A.RegionId WHERE B.Quadrant=" + i.ToString()))
                {
                    teamlist = new List<Team>();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        teamlist.Add(new Team(
                            dr["TeamId"].ToString(),
                            dr["TeamName"].ToString(),
                            Convert.ToInt16(dr["Seed"]),
                            dr["RegionId"].ToString(),
                            dr["RegionName"].ToString(),
                            Convert.ToInt16(dr["Quadrant"])
                            ));
                    }
                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case 1: LoadButtons(Quad1, teamlist); break;
                        case 2: LoadButtons(Quad2, teamlist); break;
                        case 3: LoadButtons(Quad3, teamlist); break;
                        case 4: LoadButtons(Quad4, teamlist); break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        FFButtons = new Dictionary<Button, Team>();
        FTButtons = new Dictionary<Button, Team>();
        Winner = new Team();

        FFButtons.Add(btnQ1FFL, new Team());
        FFButtons.Add(btnQ2FFL, new Team());
        FFButtons.Add(btnQ3FFR, new Team());
        FFButtons.Add(btnQ4FFR, new Team());
        FTButtons.Add(btnLFT, new Team());
        FTButtons.Add(btnRFT, new Team());

        Session["TeamButtons"] = TeamButtons;
        Session["FFButtons"] = FFButtons;
        Session["FTButtons"] = FTButtons;
        Session["Winner"] = Winner;

        ResetWinners(64);
    }
    else
    {
        TeamButtons = (Dictionary<Button, Team>)Session["TeamButtons"];
        FFButtons = (Dictionary<Button, Team>)Session["FFButtons"];
        FTButtons = (Dictionary<Button, Team>)Session["FTButtons"];
        Winner = (Team)Session["Winner"];
    }

    LoadTeams();

}
```

Load Buttons:

```
private void LoadButtons(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable table, List<Team> teamlist)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow c in table.Rows)
    {
        foreach (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell d in c.Cells)
        {
            foreach (Control f in d.Controls)
            {
                if (f is Button)
                {
                    TeamButtons.Add((Button)f, teamlist[i]);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LoadTeams:

```
private void LoadTeams()
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Button, Team> tb in TeamButtons)
    {
        tb.Key.Text = TeamText(tb.Value);
        switch (tb.Value.Quadrant)
        {
            case 1:
                tb.Key.Click += new EventHandler(Tournament1_Click);
                break;
            case 2:
                tb.Key.Click += new EventHandler(Tournament2_Click);
                break;
            case 3:
                tb.Key.Click += new EventHandler(Tournament3_Click);
                break;
            case 4:
                tb.Key.Click += new EventHandler(Tournament4_Click);
                break;
        }
    }
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Button, Team> tb in FFButtons)
    {
        tb.Key.Text = TeamText(tb.Value);
        if (tb.Value.Quadrant <= 2) tb.Key.Click += new EventHandler(TournamentFourL_Click);
        else tb.Key.Click += new EventHandler(TournamentFourR_Click);
    }
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Button, Team> tb in FTButtons)
    {
        tb.Key.Text = TeamText(tb.Value);
        tb.Key.Click += new EventHandler(TournamentTwo_Click);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not databind the the teams to a grid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The handlers need to be added on every page cycle in the oninit method.  Try that and see what happens.  If that doesn't work, try posting some more complete page code.  Also, if that doesn't work, can you specify how the buttons are created?  Are they just present in the aspx or are they dynamically created?  If they are dynamically created, make sure you assign an ID to each of them on creation.

Comment: Should also be mentioned that the controls themselves need to exist before OnLoad is fired.

Comment: The controls are in the aspx. Interestingly enough, I tried a similar, albeit much smaller scale solution here at home with a new ASP.NET website, and the issue doesn't exist. I will try using the OnInit method when I get back in on Monday and let you know. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @stringpoet : If the controls are already in the aspx, you can just assign the event handler in the aspx itself and save yourself the trouble of having to set it up in the oninit.

Comment: Well, yes, I could do that...if I wanted to write 70 event handler additions and have them clutter my cs file. :)

Comment: You can have all of them point to the same handler.  It's the same thing as manually wiring, just declarative.  Look at OnCommand instead of OnClick.

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to, swannee. I'm familiar with the CommandEventHandler, but I'd still have to write out the declaration for each button. There are 6 different events.

Comment: I put the code in the oninit override and still no luck. It's worth noting that before, I was storing the buttons in a List<Button> and it worked fine then. I must have screwed something up along the way that I'm not seeing. :)

Comment: Final four and final two. The only rounds in this that are used are the first round, and the final two rounds.

Comment: If I remove the part that runs on a postback in the page load using the session variables, this entire problem goes away. FYI

Comment: This basic approach needs some rework and you've gotten so far I'm not sure what to tell you.  When a page is rebuilt on a postback, all of the controls of the page are also rebuilt.  Then viewstate is applied to the controls to bring them up to date.  That's why you have to reassociate the event handlers on each postback.  The problem is that you are taking these buttons and storing them in the session (unless I am reading wrong).  You should never do this because those buttons that are in session are from the first load of the page.  The page has no idea what those buttons are on postback.

Comment: If anything, I think the good news is that you've overcomplicated this thing IMO.  It could be a lot simpler.

Comment: The buttons are just stored in the Dictionary so I can relate them to the team associated to the button, which is then placed in a session variable. Each selection needs to be stored in the database for each person, so I think it has to be this complicated, unless I'm just over-thinking it. When I check the dictionary after a postback, the buttons are all there with their teams. The problem is the handlers not being rebuilt.

Comment: Right, but after a postback, those buttons in the dictionary are no longer the buttons on your page.  The buttons in the dictionary are retrieved out of session.  Sure they are there because you stored the objects there.  But after a postback you now have two sets of buttons.  The buttons on your page (recreated after postback) and the buttons that you stored in session state which are no longer associated with your page.  When you reassign the event handlers, you are assigning them to the buttons in session.  As mentioned these don't fire because these are no longer the buttons on your page.

Comment: ASP.Net webforms attempts to make a "stateful" programming model out of a stateless (HTTP) protocol.  But every time the page posts back every control on the page is completely instantiated anew.  So if you are holding a reference to a control created on a previous postback (which you are doing in session), you are basically holding a reference to a dead control.

Comment: Sticking with your current approach, probably the easiest way to make it work is in your LoadTeams, instead of messing with the (dead) button stored in session, use the identifying info from that button to find the (live) button on the page.  Once you find that button, associate the event handler and other properties with it.  If anything, you only need to store the ids of the different buttons in the session state, not the entire control.

Comment: Alright, that worked. I just used a temporary dictionary object to refill in LoadTeams. Thanks!

Comment: Cool!  But if you are following my point about session, storing UI controls in session typically means you went off the yellow brick road somewhere, so you may want to reevaluate that approach if you didn't already.  Good luck!

Comment: I'd like to, but time is pressing for this project at work, and it's a temporary solution. I'm still adjusting to the idiosyncrasies of ASP.NET compared to standalone applications. ;)

Comment: yeah, web forms can be jacked up if you're not used to it.  If you haven't already I'd make a bee line for asp.net MVC on your next ASP.Net project.  Not that it's necessarily easier, but it's a better pattern, cleaner, and more apparent what's happening.  It embraces the stateless nature of http instead of trying to hide it.

Answer (score 2):

The pages in ASP.NET are recreated every time a request is made, therefore all the dynamically added event handlers are lost with each new request. So as swannee already said, you need to add them in the OnInit method (OnLoad, Page_Load would work too) every time the page is requested. If you are interested in understanding the ASP.NET page life cycle better, check [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).